# $ \min _{\operatorname{rank}\{\boldsymbol{B}\}=\boldsymbol{k}<r=rank(A)}\|\boldsymbol{A}-B\|_{2} ,A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ and A is given

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-rank, matrix-norms

I would like to solve the following minimization problem.$$
\min _{\operatorname{rank}\{\boldsymbol{B}\}=\boldsymbol{k}<r=rank(A)}\|\boldsymbol{A}-\boldsymbol{B}\|_{2} ,\boldsymbol{A,B} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}
$$ where
$
A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}, \operatorname{rank}\{A\}=r, 2 \leq r \leq \min \{m, n\}
$ **is a given matrix**.

My idea at first was to go with SVD and try to rewrite the norm. But I didn't reach an interesting result.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum does not exist, but the infimum is zero.

For example: for any $\epsilon > 0$, the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{\epsilon \cdot I_k & 0_{k\times (n-k)}\\ 0_{(m-k)\times k}& 0_{(m-k) \times (m-k)}}, \quad 
B = \pmatrix{\epsilon \cdot I_r & 0_{r\times (n-r)}\\ 0_{(m-r)\times r}& 0_{(m-r) \times (m-r)}}
$$
satisfy the constraints with $\|A - B\|_2 = \epsilon$ (assuming $\|\cdot\|_2$ refers to the spectral norm).

Comment: ∥⋅∥2 is different from the Frobenius norm. Actually || . ||F >= || . ||2. How to prove that the minimum doesn't exist from those matrices??

Comment: @why_me I've edited my post. The point is that by making $\epsilon$ smaller, $\|A - B\|_2$ can be made as small as we'd like. In other words, no positive number can be the minimum value. On the other hand, $\|A - B\|_2$ can never be zero within the constraints of the problem because the ranks imply that $A \neq B$, which means that $0$ also can't be the minimum value.

Comment: Actually, matrix A cannot be specified in that form because It is a given matrix.

Comment: @why_me It would have been helpful if you explained the problem more clearly. With you post as it stands, it seems that you're looking for a low-rank approximation for $A$, which can be attained using a [truncated SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_spectral_norm)).